# Can I configure my Xfinity router without the app?

Tags: router, internet-connection, wifi-configuration

I've been configuring my routers for decades with their built-in HTTP servers.  Yesterday I signed up for new Xfinity home internet service, and they said I had to download their mobile app in order to change my router settings.

Is there truly no way to manually configure these Comcast routers?

Comment: "Is there truly no way to manually configure these Comcast routers?" - You can navigate to the device on the network and login as the Administrator.  If you don't have the Administrator password or a password, that is something we can't help you with.  You should be able to determine the IP address of the device using `ipconfig /all`

Comment: Of course, thank you.  I was trying the wrong address for the router.  And the default login and password were available on the web.